# AI - Breaking a mesh into a grid of vector shapes

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs6, gradient-mesh

I've researched for what seems forever, and I cannot find anything explaining **how to break a mesh into a (distorted) grid of vector shapes**. I *don't* need to preserve any kind of gradient or coloring; I just, at least, need to keep the shape of the outline of the figure and convert it into a basic shape.

The concept is, I've used a mesh to distort a figure, but I now need to restore it back into a vector shape. If I can at least break the mesh into a grid of vector shapes, I can join them with the 'Pathfinder > Shape Modes > Unite'.

Comment: gradient meshes only expand to rasters, I fear. sad. because they use the gradient tool on lines as a gradient mesh. Which is great, until you need to change the line (with the gradient following it, in "apply gradient along stroke")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without seeing the art, it's a bit difficult to give exact direction. However you should be able to do the following:

Select the Mesh.

Choose `Object > Path > Offset Path` and insert a value of 0.

This will create a new object which matches the outline of the mesh shape exactly.

If you need objects for each internal part of the mesh, John's suggestion to expand may help. Sometimes a combination of expanding and pathfinder can be helpful.

Another possible option is the select the mesh and use `Object > Rasterize`. Then use Image Trace to trace the shape.

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I was looking for! Sorry if I was confusing. And I knew about Rasterizing and retracing, but that would have been my last resort, due to imprecision and likely extra unnecessary vectors.  --  (I'll 1+ your answer when I get 15 rep)

Comment: Glad that helps. And I agree.. rasterizing and retracing is a last resort. But that at least gets vectors which you can then refine.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but have you tried `Object` → `Expand`? This would remove the Envelope Distort Mesh and convert it into a regular shape (no need to break apart into pieces then Unite them)

Comment: Object › Expand is grayed out when a gradient mesh is selected.

Comment: @AndrewSwift you're right about that, but the post is tagged as "gradient mesh" though the question never actually refers to one. I suspect it might be a mis-tag