# Illustrator - Break mesh into gradient squares

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg, gradient, gradient-mesh

I would like to export an illustration in Illustrator to SVG, but it doesn't support gradient mesh. Is it possible to break the mesh into squares, each one with it's gradient and export it as SVG?

Similar question with non satisfactory answer: [AI - Breaking a mesh into a grid of vector shapes](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/18084/ai-breaking-a-mesh-into-a-grid-of-vector-shapes)
The selected answer doesn't solve what is asked.

Comment: The previous answers are still the best you'll find. Gradient Meshes can not be divided or broken up and they can only be expanded to an embedded raster image with a clipping mask. Unfortunately there are *no other answers* to solve this. It's a limit of meshes in Illustrator. Sometimes, regardless of satisfaction levels, the answer is still "no". It's a bit of shame that nothing has changed in the 8 years since that original question.

Comment: A shame indeed. Web is the biggest media now, they should add some way to export it to SVG. Maybe creating a series of circles with the gradient, or something.

Comment: @vodofen - SVG currently doesn't support gradient meshes. Maybe that will change in the future.  That's why Illustrator rasterizes them.  Inkscape has gradient meshes too, but again, these are not supported in SVG. So the problem is not Illustrator specific.

Comment: To be fair.. AI's code for Gradient Meshes was probably written back in 1990 (or earlier) and hasn't changed since. It's *rare* for Adobe to *actually* spend the time to go in and update any old feature (beyond bug fixes) because spending the time on new features is seen as more profitable - i.e. NEW customers, not support for long-time existing customers (they are already hostages).